# Passing navigation to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to pass the navigation -- using React Navigation 5 -- to my component in my `stackNavigation`. Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const MyStack = new createStackNavigator();

const MyStackNav = () => {

   const navigation = useNavigation();

   return(
      <MyStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
         <MyStack.Screen name="Comp1" component={Component1} />
         <MyStack.Screen name="Comp2" component={Component2} />
      </MyStack.Navigator>
   );
}

export default MyStackNav;
```

I tried this but got an error:

```
<MyStack.Screen name="Comp1" component={(navigation) => <Component1 navigation={navigation} />} />
```

How do I pass `navigation` to my components i.e. `Component1` and `Component2`. By the way, those are class components.

Answer (score 0):

You should import `NavigationContainer` from `@react-navigation/native`. Every component within `MyStack.Screen` will receive a prop `navigation`.

Example from [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/):

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>{/* ... */}</Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have the `NavigationContainer` in my `App.js` so I'm already using the navigation container but I don't see navigation as a prop in my components. Any idea why?

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://snack.expo.io/@phos-dev/example-navigation) I made, notice that in `App.js` the `NavigationContainer` is not wrapped in a `View`.

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I figured out the issue. The structure of my app was fine. As in your example, the `NavigationContainer` wraps my navigation or other components. The issue was that I was NOT receiving `navigation` in my components. The `navigation` was missing in my components i.e. I was doing `const MyComponent = () =>`  as opposed to `const MyComponent = ({ navigation }) =>`